# Maya 2017 - Mesh Mirror results my mesh wrongly symmetry sculpt

Tags: maya

1. Assume I have a cube with:

   - subdivisions width = 4
   - subdivisions height = 4

[image: CubeMaya4x4x1]

2. I delete the 4th faces

[image: CubeMayaHalf]

3. I mirror it

[image: Maya2017MirrorSettings]

Apply the mirror then move the offset to make sure no subdivision width is hide, next I press W to complete mirror

4. Now my sculpt's symmetry is messed up, you see the symmetry is shift to the left (of the camera)

[image: Maya2017 symmetry sculpt messed up]

I have tried center pivot, freeze transformations. But nothing works.

PS: I got another clue: to make symmetry sculpt work properly, `center pivot` is not good enough, we have to `bake pivot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, according to the clue I got: to make symmetry sculpt work properly, `center pivot` is not good enough, we have to `bake pivot`.

So before mirror the object (step 3 of the question), I have to edit the pivot point (hold `D` or `insert` then drag the pivot point). See the image below:

Here I'm in front view.

1.Hold D to make the pivot point movable

[image: Hold D to make the pivot point movable]

2. Drag the mouse to move the pivot point the appropriate position

[image: move the pivot point the appropriate position]

then `bake pivot` (`Modify` > `Bake Pivot`). After that, I can mirror the cube.

Comment: Yes the pivot is not the objects origin, it because moving the origin is a rather expensive and destructive operation instead the pivot is free to move regardless of the underlying object. You can ask maya to show where the actual pivot is if you wish but not many people do that. Also baking pivot and freezing transformation are thing you should not do lightly.

Comment: @ joojaa: so you mean I should not overuse `Bake Pivot`?If I shouldn't, then is there any alternative I can fix this?

Comment: @joojaa: About `should not do lightly`, what do you mean? a feature is created to be used, I think there is no reason to not use them.

Comment: Think of it thisway, how often would you move all the vertices of the object to reposition it, instead of just moving the transform. You should use freeze transform as often as you feel the need to move all the vertices, because its exactly the same thing.

Comment: @joojaa: I just think that freeze transform is best to setup default value when I import the 3d model into game engine (very important for calculation in game engine). So instead of moving all the vertices (like you said above), just one click to freeze transform is a huge productivity boost - don't you think? :)

Comment: If that is what you intended to do. But graphic artists arent always very technical. They tend to use stuff out of reasons of magic, not always need. Freeze comes with a huge potential penalty. So when i still worked as a model l fixer, most of the problems with animation rigs breaking was due to users freezing stuff because they felt like it. One has also to remeber that the floating point values are only accurate around the origin, not pivot, so freezing can really destroy your model if you do something stupid.